# SQL Server 2014 Express - Instance is not visible in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have installed the SQL Server Express 2014, because I will create a database with Entity Framework. I don't need a remote access, because I installed Visual Studio and SQL Server Express on the same machine. But I don't have access to the SQL Server instance. Are there more steps to have access to it. The instance is running.

Thanks 
Andreas

Comment: Did you check every setting in sql configuration manager? Can you open a connection with sqlcmd in your cmd?

Comment: Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with the server and look at login page to get the instance of SSMS.  Use the instance in your connection string.

Comment: If he uses SSMS the first time, the Instance won't be there. And if he hasn't configured the server browser well, he might not find the instance. I would suggest a short look in the sql configuration manager. There you'll definitely find the correct instance name. It's not a big deal. Just a hand full of options.

Comment: Yes I think the problem is that the SQL Browser is not running. I cannot get it to work. The menu to start the service is disabled?